# Difference to connect to LDAP by BindDn or by username

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication

We have an application which can only connect to a LDAP (AD) by using the BindDn.

When I try to connect from the server which host the application using a simple LDAP client (LDAPAdmin) it connects sucessfully.

Recently the sysadmin change the AD (probably to a new machine and new version) but we cannot connect to it using the BindDn anymore, we did not change anything on the settings (BindDn string) except the ldap url pointing to the new server.

**EDIT:**

*Case 1 - connect with user/password*

```
url     = ldap://myserver.mydomain.org
BaseDn  = OU=department,DC=mydomain,DC=org
user    = myuser
passw   = password
```

*Case 2 - connect with bindDn*

```
url     = ldap://myserver.mydomain.org
BaseDn  = OU=department,DC=mydomain,DC=org
bindDn  = CN=myuser,OU=Special Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=org
bindpwd = password
```

The connection using case 1 works with the ldapAdmin as the Case 2 does not work from our app (same user and password in both cases).

UPDATE: 
Error message is here [image: LDAP Error Message]

Is there a special setting on the LDAP server side to enable to connect using BindDn?

**UPDATE:**
Apparently the former server was a `Windows 2003 Server` and the new one is `Windows 2008 Server`.

Comment: You will need to talk to the AD admin to learn what he changed and work with him to enable your app again.

Comment: Yes, this is the case and we are investigating together... but I do not have all technical details on the AD infrastructure.

Comment: Have you verified connectivity to the LDAP server on TCP port 389 from the server trying the bindDN?  What is the LDAP or application error being generated when you try to connect?

Comment: I put the error screenshot, the error 52e means the credentials are not correct. After a while the account get blocked and we get a 775 instead 52e but that is a known issue.

Answer (score -1):

LDAP admin will be Binding to database using specific credentials, you need to locate them and bind using them, but for core changes you need to find specific binding account details anyway your bind parameters will link to specific access control lists ACLs, so admin will have more privs than a user who can read the database.  OK.

Comment: I just do not understand your answer...